# Grails 2.4.4 + sitemesh.preprocess = false + render = total failure

Tags: grails, sitemesh

I started using Grails 2.4.4 recently after a long time of 2.2.3. Now I want to migrate some projects.
Here's my problem: I need grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = false and my actions need to invoke "render" to tell which GSP should handle the rendering.

Now with a **brand new project** (but with the migrated ones as well), by doing so I get:
a:
   `Message: null
    ->>  195 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    |     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter 
    |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread`

I'm currently using a specific view.dir, but falling back to detail doesn't seem to do any good.
My test controller is just like this:

    `def index() {
        render(view:'/main/index')
    }`

Anyone experienced something like this? I'm not aware if it's something related to the latest release or was present before. It certainly wasn't in Grails 2.2.3.

Update: by disabling the "cache" plugin that looked somehow involved, all I get is:

    `Message: null
    Line | Method
    ->> 1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread`

so the problem looks deep within

Comment: Tried in a vanilla 2.3.9 app with the preprocessing option disabled and it works.

Comment: Will try that. At least it's an upgrade. Some time ago I tried the 2.3 line and had other issues. Let's see if I can make this thing work

Comment: I noticed a difference between the 2.3.9 and the 2.4.4 debug logs: `DEBUG mvc.SimpleGrailsController  - [SimpleGrailsController] Forwarding model and view [ModelAndView: reference to view with name '/prova/vista'; model is {}] with class [/prova/vista]` says that the model map is empty in 2.4.4, but in the 2.3.9 app this is populated with the all the objects related to the request, the response and all the rest.

Comment: Weird. In grails 2.4.5, I can enable the sitemash preprocessing and have it working as expected...